# How to find out what app is sending an AWS SNS text message (SMS) or at least what was the text of that failed message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

So we have a many node.js EC2 apps (and also many node.js lambda funcs) which send AWS SNS messages to users' phones (an SMS text message).
We have special code in each of those apps (and lambda funcs) which doesn't send out the SMS if the user types a special test phone # (like 999-999-9999 pretend, as it would be wasteful to send to that fake test #... this is so our QA Team can use this special # in their regular or load testing without worry that AWS will charge us for trying to send to it).
Yet we are seeing some texts are still trying to go through when we check the logs (aka the SNS->'Text messaging (SMS)'->'Delivery status logs' area in AWS).
Here is for example what you see in that default report (there is a 'message id' in there, but I'm not sure if you can use that to find what was the text itself):
[Pic of AWS Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPuNu.png)

Is there anyway to see the source of the SMS? Or even what was the text of that message (as that could also be used to determine which app or lambda it came from).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only way was to log all the status to AWS CloudWatch and search from there using the MessageId.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html

Follow this process and make the sample rate to 100% to log all the respose. Once you enable the CloudWatch for SNS, both success and failure logs will also be added into different log streams.

I hope you find this helpful.